# javascript returning function as an object property

Tags: javascript, object, fs

I'm doing a program where I have to return information about a file in an object.The object contains four properties:
1st property named : `birthTime` : which contains the birth time of the file in ms.
2nd property named : `modifiedTime` : which contains the time at which file is modified in ms.
3rd property named : `size` : which contains the size of the file.
4th property named : `type` : which contains the type of the file i.e whether it is a file or a directory.

My code is:

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
var obj = {birthTime: stats.birthtimeMs , 
    modifiedTime: stats.mtimeMs , 
    size: stats.size , 
    type: function(){if(stats.isFile()===true){return "File"}
                          else{return "Directory"}}}
    console.log(obj);
});
```

When I run it , I get:
`{ birthTime: 2019-07-16T18:00:51.674Z,
  modifiedTime: 2019-07-16T18:00:51.674Z,
  size: 327,
  type: [Function: type] }`

How do I make the code return `"File"` instead of `[Function: type]`?

Comment: You need to execute the function, just add () at the end of the definition. Anyways is a better practice to define the function before your object and then executing it where you are defining it at the moment.

Comment: By using IIFE: `type: (function () {
            if (stats.isFile() === true) { return "File" }
            else { return "Directory" }
        })()`.

Comment: Don't use a function. Get `type` to variable before this literal is created or use ternary

Comment: Use -  **type: stats.isFile() === true ? "File" : "Directory"** and why were you putting this condition in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
    var obj = {
        birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
        modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
        size: stats.size , 
        type: stats.isFile() ? "File" : "Directory"
    };
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Use an IIFE

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
    var obj = {
        birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
        modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
        size: stats.size , 
        type: (function(){
            if(stats.isFile()) {
                return "File";
            } else {
                return "Directory";
            }
        })()
    };
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Declare the function elsewhere and call it

```
function checkType(stats) {
    return stats.isFile() ? "File" : "Directory";
}

const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
    var obj = {
        birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
        modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
        size: stats.size , 
        type: checkType(stats)
    };
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Calculate the value in a variable and store it

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
    var type = stats.isFile() ? "File" : "Directory";
    var obj = {
        birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
        modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
        size: stats.size , 
        type: type 
    };
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the function, and use the ternary operator instead:

```
type: stats.isFile() ? 'File' : 'Directory'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it as an `IIFE` (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
var obj = {birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
size: stats.size , 
type: (function(){if(stats.isFile()===true){return "File"}
                      else{return "Directory"}}})()
console.log(obj);
});
```

or

Try `ternary` operator

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("./fs1.js", function(err, stats){
var obj = {birthTime: stats.birthtime , 
modifiedTime: stats.mtime , 
size: stats.size , 
type: stats.isFile()?"File":"Directory",
console.log(obj);
});
```

---

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
type: stats.isFile() ? 'File' : 'Directory'
```